# Changing Widget Size

Tags: kivy

So I have a game where I have a picture of a tree, and a moveable character.  I was unable to get collide_widget working, and couldn't figure out why.  I opened up Kivy Inspector and discovered that when I click on my moveable character there is a small red box, but when I click on the picture of the tree, the entire kivy window turns red, so I'm guessing that the widget size is as large as the entire window (this also explains why collide_widget was always showing True).  To fix this, I was told to add size_hint = None and specify the size of the tree.  I did this when I instantiated the tree in the build, but the entire screen still turns red which i click on the tree.

So is my problem that the the widget tree is inside of is too big?  How do I make it smaller?  Adding size_hint=None and changing size to 50,50 did't fix it, unless I did this incorrectly.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FallOutTransition


gamelayout = RelativeLayout(size=(300, 300))
bglayout = RelativeLayout()

class Game(Screen):
    pass    

class Bg(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bg, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.allow_stretch = True
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (1440, 1440)


class MoveableImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)
        self.size_hint = (.11, .11)
        self.y = (Window.height/2.1)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()

    def collide_with_tree(self, tree):
        if self.widget_collide(self.app.tree):
            print "success"


    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            print self.pos
            print self.app.tree.pos
            self.collide_with_tree(self.app.tree)
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x < (Window.width * .25):
                bglayout.x += 4
            else:
                self.x -= 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x > (Window.width * .70):
                bglayout.x -= 4
            else:
                self.x += 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.y < (Window.height * .25):
                bglayout.y += 4
            else:
                self.y -= 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/back.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.1
            if self.y > (Window.height * .70):
                bglayout.y -= 4
            else:
                self.y += 6
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/back2.png'
        else:
            return False
        return True


class gameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global sm
        sm = ScreenManager()
        game = Game(name='game')
        sm.add_widget(game)
        hero = MoveableImage(source='selectionscreen/right1.png')
        self.tree = Image(source='selectionscreen/tree.zip', size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50))
        self.background=Bg(source='selectionscreen/background9.png')

        #add widgets to bglayout
        bglayout.add_widget(self.background)
        bglayout.add_widget(self.tree)

        #add bglayout and moveable hero to gamelayout
        gamelayout.add_widget(bglayout)
        gamelayout.add_widget(hero)
        game.add_widget(gamelayout)

        return sm



if __name__ == '__main__':
    gameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **FloatLayout** instead of a RelativeLayout (or just add a FloatLayout to the ScreenManager's Screen (which is a RelativeLayout), and put all your game widgets inside the FloatLayout instead.

So, you need something like this:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
game_screen = Screen()
game = FloatLayout()
game_screen.add_widget(game)
```

..and then add all your game widgets to game so that the sizes are fixed and not made "relative" to the parent layout maanger.